# Fading image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart

[image]

Can anyone please explain how to get this image shading effect in Flutter.

Comment: you can use `LinearGradient` on `Container` with `Stack`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to get the fading out background. The best way to do it is to use a Stack, with your background image at the bottom, a gradient going from your background color to transparent above it, and then your UI elements above that. Here is a working example build:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          Image.asset('assets/background.jpg', fit: BoxFit.cover,),
          Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.topCenter, end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.white],
                stops: [0, .4]
              )
            ),
          ),
          Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: const [
                    Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                    Expanded(child: Center(child: Text('Steve Johnson',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)
                    ))),
                    Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline_sharp)
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 32,),
                Container(
                  height: 96, width: 96,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.deepOrange, width: 4),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: Image.asset('assets/profile.jpg',
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,),
                ),
              ],
            )
          )
        ]
      )
    );
  }
```

[image: Running code]